# In a bash script, loop through a bash array for input to a binary

Tags: shell-script, array

I'm running bash.

- Suppose I have a binary `mybinary` that takes interactive user input.
- Suppose that `mybinary` takes attendee names as input until the user types `q` and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`q` for "quit").
- I can automate the input process in a bash script by surrounding the input by `<<EOF`/`EOF`.
  For example, suppose I want to enter predefined user input from an array `myarray`. I can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

myarray=("Alice" "Bob" "Charlie" "q") # q quits the binary

mybinary -f inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt<<EOF
${myarray[0]}
${myarray[1]}
${myarray[2]}
${myarray[3]}
EOF
```

I tested the above, and it works. But it's laborious to type `${myarray[X]}` for every index in `myarray` if `myarray` has hundreds of (string) elements.

**How can I modify the above bash script to loop through `myarray`?**

The following won't work because the `for`, `do`, and `done` parts will be taken as input to `mybinary`:

```
#!/bin/bash

myarray=("Alice" "Bob" "Charlie" "q") # q quits the binary

mybinary -f inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt<<EOF
for element in "${myarray[@]}"
do
${myarray[0]}
${myarray[1]}
${myarray[2]}
${myarray[3]}
done
EOF
```

Moreover, I can't simply place the `for` loop *around* the call to `mybinary`, because I don't want multiple calls to `mybinary`. **So how can I loop through an array to use the array's elements as input to `mybinary`?**

Comment: Is a here-document really necessary in this case? If `mybinary` is reading lines from stdin, wouldn't `printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}" | mybinary -f inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt` suffice?

Comment: Not that you couldn't do it with a loop too: `for x in "${myarray[@]}"; do echo "$x"; done`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `printf` to add newlines after each entry in the array:

```
myarray=("Alice" "Bob" "Charlie" "q")

mybinary -f inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt<<EOF
$(printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}")
EOF
```

As doneal24 and steeldriver pointed out, you could also use a pipe rather than a here-document:

```
printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}" | mybinary -f inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Why the heredoc? Piping printf to the binary saves a step.

Comment: @doneal24 Good point; I'll add it as an option.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

myarray=("Alice" "Bob" "Charlie" "q") # q quits the binary

mybinary -f inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt < <(printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}")
```

If your binary is well coded, it should be deal with `STDIN` transparently.

Comment: Actually, the `-f` flag should be followed by the name of the (external) input file, `inputfile.txt`. Once `mybinary -f inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt` is called, the user is promted for input -- that's the part I want to automate with `myarray` and `printf`, etc. In that case, then, where do I put the `/dev/stdin`?

Comment: If your binary is well coded, it should be deal with `STDIN` transparently

Answer (score 1):

To print the elements of an array one per line, in zsh, you do:

```
print -rC1 -- "$array[@]"
```

Or:

```
print -rNC1 -- "$array[@]"
```

for NUL-delimited records instead of lines.

(`print -rC1 -- $array` would only print the non-empty elements).

`bash` has a `print` builtin (initially from ksh), but only as an optional loadable builtin and it doesn't support the `-C` option (nor `-N`).

`printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"` doesn't work correctly for empty arrays as it prints an empty line (as if the array had one empty element) instead of no line at all.

The common way in bash (or POSIX shells¹ in general) is to define some helper functions:

```
println() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }
print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
```

Then, you can do:

```
println "${array[@]}" q | your-cmd
```

---

<sup>¹ beware though that some POSIX shells (mostly ksh88 and some pdksh-based ones) don't have `printf` builtin, so won't be able to output large lists as you'll soon reach the limit on the size of the arguments that can be passed to an external command.</sup>